# unique by multiple columns and NULL values

Tags: mysql, symfony-1.4

I'm developing using symfony 1.4 (and Doctrine) and have a MySQL database table with an unique index on multiple columns. First, the YAML definition of the table so far:

```
Campaign:
  actAs:
    Sluggable:
      fields: [name]
      canUpdate: true
      uniqueBy: [merchant_id, deleted_at]
    Timestampable: ~
    SoftDelete: ~
  columns:
    merchant_id:      { type: integer, notnull: true }
    name:             { type: string(255), notnull: true, notblank: true }
    start_date:       { type: date, notnull: true, notblank: true }
    end_date:         { type: date, notnull: true, notblank: true }
  indexes:
    unique_name:  { fields: [name, merchant_id, deleted_at], type: unique }
  relations:
    Merchant: { local: merchant_id, foreign: id }
```

As you can see, I have to deal with campaigns belonging to merchants. A campaign knows its merchant and has a name (as well as a start date and an end date). The name of a campaign should be unique -- not globally but for that specific merchant. Up to here, I would need a unique index on the campaign name and the respective merchant. But, as the table "acts as SoftDelete" and the user should be able to create a new campaign with a name that already exists for a "soft-deleted" campaign, the `deleted_at` column also has to be part of the unique index. You see, the uniqueness of a campaign's name concerns only not deleted campaigns of the respective merchant.

Now coming to the **actual problem**: As column `deleted_at` is NULL for all not deleted campaigns and NULL values within a unique index are always treated as being unique, all campaigns are allowed to have non-unique names -- in the true sense. I know, this applies for MyISAM and InnoDB tables but not for BDB tables. However, switching to BDB is not my favourite option, if you know what I mean.

Now coming to the **actual question**: What are other possible options in addition to changing the MySQL engine to BDB? A workaround could be to rename a campaign that is soft-deleted, e.g. `name = 'DELETED AT ' + deleted_at + ': ' + name`. This, on the one hand, would have the advantage that all soft-deleted campaigns would expectedly have unique names even in the case in which they are restored (resetting `deleted_at` back to NULL). The `deleted_at` column wouldn't have to be part of the unique index any longer and, thus, all campaigns (not deleted, soft-deleted as well as restored once) would have a unique name -- concerning the respective merchant. But, on the other hand, I don't think this would be the most elegant solution. What are your opinions and expertise on this?

I thank you very much and am happy about your contributions.
Flinsch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can keep your basic structure, you just need a way to make deleted_at NOT NULL. That means you'll need to give it a default. A good default to use is 0, or 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

My recommendation is to add a new column to flag whether the rows is logically deleted. You can call it "IS_DELETED". Then add the default for deleted_at and make it non-null, and include is_deleted in your unique index.

Here's a very simple example of this approach in action:

```
mysql> create table merchant(
    -> id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    -> name varchar(50) not null, 
    -> is_deleted tinyint not null default 0, 
    -> deleted_at datetime not null default 0,
    -> primary key (id),
    -> unique key name_and_deleted_at (name,is_deleted,deleted_at)
    -> ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> -- successful inserts
mysql> insert into merchant (name,is_deleted) values ('foo',0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into merchant (name,is_deleted) values ('bar',0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> -- insert failure due to duplicate name
mysql> insert into merchant (name,is_deleted) values ('foo',0);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'foo-0-0000-00-00 00:00:00' for key 'name_and_deleted_at'
mysql> -- logical delete
mysql> update merchant set is_deleted = true, deleted_at = now() where name = 'foo';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> -- now the insert succeeds
mysql> insert into merchant (name,is_deleted) values ('foo',0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> -- show data
mysql> select id,name,is_deleted,deleted_at 
    -> from merchant
    -> order by id;
+----+------+------------+---------------------+
| id | name | is_deleted | deleted_at          |
+----+------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 | foo  |          1 | 2010-11-05 13:54:17 |
|  2 | bar  |          0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  4 | foo  |          0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+------+------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ike, thanks for your response. I had a very similar idea as well. And I think that the additional flag `is_deleted` is not really needed as I can check `deleted_at` to be 0 or not. However, I have previously shunned it, because I do not know exactly if manually setting `deleted_at` to a NOT NULL value would cause unforeseen consequences regarding the generation of object lists etc. -- as `deleted_at` is something like a "magic column" of symfony/Doctrine. But I think I'll give it a try... :)

Comment: MySQL 5.7 can help out with virtual columns!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064759/how-to-do-unique-constraint-works-with-null-value-in-mysql/42291845#42291845