# How to do unique constraint works with NULL value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, null, duplicates, constraints

I am looking for how to implement unique constraints with NULL check.

MySQL shouldn't allow multiple null value.

Employee:

```
id | name
---|-----
1  | null
2  | null -> should give error during inserting  2nd row.
```

Comment: Can you share what you get error?

Comment: i am asking how to achieve it. Now it is inserting  multiple null into db

Answer (score 11):

MySQL 5.7 does allow for a workaround:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `null_test` (
    ->   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `const` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

With soft deletes, it would be nice if you could have just one row with a with a `deleted_at = NULL` per constraint.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `null_test` ADD `vconst` int(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (((NULL = `deleted_at`) or (NULL <=> `deleted_at`))) VIRTUAL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

So I created a virtual column that will flip from `1` to `null` when `deleted_at` gets set.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `null_test` ADD UNIQUE KEY `nullable_index` (`const`,`vconst`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Instead of including `deleted_at` to the unique constraint add the virtual column, `vconst`.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `null_test` SET `const` = 'Ghost';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `null_test` WHERE `const` = 'Ghost';
+--------+-------+------------+--------+
| id     | const | deleted_at | vconst |
+--------+-------+------------+--------+
| 999901 | Ghost | NULL       |      1 |
+--------+-------+------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

No need to insert the `vconst` (but you cannot, anyhow).

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `null_test` SET `const` = 'Ghost';
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'Ghost-1' for key 'nullable_index'
```

Inserting it again throws the Duplicate entry error.

```
mysql> UPDATE `null_test` SET `deleted_at` = NOW() WHERE `const` = 'Ghost';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Same with setting `delete_at`, no need to touch `vconst`, it will flip automatically.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `null_test` WHERE `const` = 'Ghost';
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+
| id     | const | deleted_at          | vconst |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 999901 | Ghost | 2017-02-16 22:07:45 |   NULL |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `null_test` SET `const` = 'Ghost';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Now you are free to insert a new row with the same constraints!

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `null_test` WHERE `const` = 'Ghost';
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+
| id     | const | deleted_at          | vconst |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+
| 999901 | Ghost | 2017-02-16 22:07:45 |   NULL |
| 999903 | Ghost | NULL                |      1 |
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

In this case, depending on how much you soft delete, setting `deleted_at`, you might want to include `deleted_at` to the index, or a new index with it, but I will let my load tests decide.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD v_column int(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (((NULL = deleted_at) or (NULL <=> deleted_at))) VIRTUAL;`

That and using the v_column in the unique index is what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

No, MySQL is doing the right thing, according to the SQL-99 specification.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/constraint_type-unique-constraint/

> A UNIQUE Constraint makes it impossible to COMMIT any operation that
>   would cause the unique key to contain any non-null duplicate values.
>   (Multiple null values are allowed, since the null value is never equal
>   to anything, even another null value.)

If you use a UNIQUE constraint but don't want multiple rows with NULL, declare the columns as `NOT NULL` and prohibit *any* row from having NULL.

Comment: Well, my problem is that I want to define a unique key over two columns, where I want to have only a unique combination. And this situation allows me to have (NULL, NULL) multiple times, which is not unique for my needs. So this situation is a little bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table yourtable add column `virtual_null` varchar(20)  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if(isnull(`your_nullable_column`),'null',`your_nullable_column`))) VIRTUAL;

alter table yourtable add constraint unique(virtual_null);
```

Make this and be happy, behind the scenes mysql's null is a hash value. Because that its impossible compare two null values...

Sorry by poor english, good luck